# C++ cURL Refresh Page

Tags: c++, curl, refresh

I have the following code in C++

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iostream>
#include <curl/curl.h>
#include <string.h>

using namespace std;



int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
   CURL *curl;
  CURLcode res;

  curl = curl_easy_init();
  if(curl) {
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_URL, "http://example.com/mypage.html");
    /* example.com is redirected, so we tell libcurl to follow redirection */ 
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1L);

    /* Perform the request, res will get the return code */ 
    res = curl_easy_perform(curl);
    /* Check for errors */ 
    if(res != CURLE_OK)
      fprintf(stderr, "curl_easy_perform() failed: %s\n",
              curl_easy_strerror(res));

    /* always cleanup */ 
    curl_easy_cleanup(curl);
  }
    system("PAUSE");
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

When I'm running this program it is showing the source code of mypage.html on the console. Next I updated the source code of mypage.html and again executed the program, but it was printing the previous source code on the console again. Where's the problem? Please Help.

Comment: Does your web browser confirm that the source has changed?

Comment: Are you sure you modified the *correct* file? I.e. the one on the server at that specific address? Other than that, I don't think cURL does any caching, but it might be worth checking out.

Comment: Yes. I'm sure I've edited the correct file. And the updated source is being printed whenever I refresh the URL from IE.

Comment: @DrewDormann Which browser? IE or other ones?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I faced the same problem recently. But it was with WinINet, not with cURL. Simply I changed my .html file to .php on my server and it worked fine! Actually .php files aren't cached by browser. So give it a try.

Answer (score 0):

I think you rewrite source code of the page, but remember update page on web server or page cashed

Comment: Yes I rewrited the source code. But how can I update the page?

Comment: What do you use as web server?

Comment: WEB hosting or VPS/VDS?

Comment: Isn't there any other way to update page without uploading new file?

Comment: No. cURL gets file from server. So if you modified file on your computer, but doesn't upload it on server, cURL gets old file.

Comment: No no..Maybe you've misunderstood. This is what I'm doing- First of all I've created a page on my server named mypage.html. My Program prints its source on the console when executed. Next I used a PHP script from my server to change the page source & again executed the program. But I was getting the old source again.

Comment: So you have got 2 pages:
1. Static page
2. PHP script that update first file

Is it so?